# Checkbox doesn't want to toggle enable disable field

Tags: javascript, html, css, checkbox

I have a check box and a field. By default the field needs to be disabled. As soon as the check box is checked, the field should enable.

I've tried literally every answer here but with no luck. I've tried css only but I failed there too. When I try some of the samples in fiddle or where ever else they work, but in my project they don't.

What I currently have is a simple test that when I click anything with `#clicker`, the field disables/enables. That works perfectly. So I know my JavaScript work, so I don't require any extra libraries whatsoever. Now I just need to adjust my code to work when a check box is checked or not.

This is what I have;

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$().ready(function() {
    $('#clicker').click(function() {
        $('#form_secondApprover').each(function() {
            if ($(this).attr('disabled')) {
                $(this).removeAttr('disabled');
            }
            else {
                $(this).attr({
                    'disabled': 'disabled'
                });
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: post your html code please.

Comment: I assume that `form_secondApprover` is the id of the form right? If it is then the one that you should disable are the `:input` elements of it, and not the form itself.

Comment: No, the form's name is form, and all the field elements inside it gets the 'form_' prefix. The form and form elements is generated by the Symfony framework. I also make use of Sonata Admin Bundle that complicates everything even more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Here is a pure `javaScript` solution for your answer !!

```js
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) {
    var checkbox = document.getElementById('clicker');
    var inputs = document.querySelectorAll('input[type=text]');
    checkbox.addEventListener('change', function(event) {
        for (var i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++) {
            inputs[i].disabled = !checkbox.checked;
        }
    });
});
```

```css
input[type="text"]:disabled {
  cursor: not-allowed;
}
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" id="clicker" />
<label for="clicker">Click Me, I'll disable/enable these text boxes</label>

<form id="form_secondApprover">
  <input type="text" disabled/>
  <input type="text" disabled/>
  <input type="text" disabled/>
</form>
```

Here is the **[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/jn7Aj/153/)** if you want to play with :)

Comment: Thanks for the pure javaScript answer. Unfortunately this on also doesn't work in my project. I think I know what the problem is. The way Sonata Admin Bundle generate forms and how it make things look "fancy" is ridiculous. It appears that the actual checkboxes get divs over them to make a 'fake better looking' checkbox and that mess everything up, same goes for select fields etc...

Comment: oh. its seems complicated. is your site is live ?

Comment: No, sorry. It is a private site for a company. Something like a CMS. I guess I can show some page source code.

Comment: @Mentos93 ok. post it in a fiddle and I will give a try :)

Answer (score 1):

**[Working fiddle with form](https://jsfiddle.net/jnwrc5ay/166/)**

Attach `change()` event to the checkbox then toggle the `disabled` attribute, check the example bellow.

**NOTE :** The fields with `disabled` will not submited, if you want to submit also the disabled ones use `readonly` instead.

Hope this helps.

---

### Simple snippet version

```js
$().ready(function() {
  $('#checkbox').on('change', function() {
    if ($('#field').attr('disabled')) {
      $('#field').removeAttr('disabled');
    }else {
      $('#field').attr({'disabled': 'disabled'});
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type='checkbox' name="checkbox1" id="checkbox" />Enable
<br>
<input type='text' name="text1" id="field" disabled/>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It works, but only if I add `<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>`. By adding that all other JavaScript in my entire project doesn't work anymore. 

I use Symfony with an extra bundle; Sonata. And by adding that one source line, everything else breaks (all javascript).

Comment: You're welcome,I think the jquery is already loaded elsewhere, try to remove the line..

Answer (score 0):

Try this

JS:

```
document.getElementById("clicker").addEventListener("change",function(event){
     if(event.target.checked)
        document.getElementById("field").removeAttribute("disabled");
     else
        document.getElementById("field").setAttribute("disabled","disabled");
});
```

HTML :

```
 <input type="checkbox" id="clicker" />
 <input type="text" id="field" disabled>
```

Comment: It is working fine for me. please post your HTML for better understanding.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the jQuery `.disabled` and `.checked` properties.

Did you mean something like this? https://jsfiddle.net/9rn9L1r9/1/

Comment: All the answers works, but none does in my project. I use the Symfony framework with Sonata Admin Bundle and that bundle complicates everything. The browser won't be the problem.